# Create File Association for a Media Player

Tags: java, registry, file-association, jsmooth

I had once created a Media Player in Java. Now I want to use it as default Media Player app to open media files. I have succeeded to create file a association so I can open local files. 
I have created an executable file for the application using jsmooth. 
The problem I have encountered, however, is that I don't get my application listed in the 'open with' list.
[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/320Fi.png)

What I have still tried is to look other application's registry settings and also microsoft registry tutorials but i didn't understand it very well.

Can anyone of you please lead me into the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: thanks naytzyrhc for suggesting an edit.